# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "vendors_vendor" does not exist

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-organizations

I am using [`django-organisations`](https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations) to have multiple user-accounts in multiple organisations. However, it is single-schema architecture. In order to make it separate-schema architecture, I am using [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants). This is my project structure:-

```
app->
-------vendors/
-------accounts/
-------conf/
-------templates/
-------manage.py
```

I have following code:-

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.db import models
from django_tenants.models import TenantMixin, DomainMixin

from organizations.abstract import (
    AbstractOrganization,
    AbstractOrganizationOwner,
    AbstractOrganizationUser,
)


class Vendor(AbstractOrganization, TenantMixin):
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.Account", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="vendors"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schema_name


class VendorUser(AbstractOrganizationUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="")
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, blank=True)


class VendorOwner(AbstractOrganizationOwner, DomainMixin):
    pass
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Django settings for conf project.

settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
        "default": {
                        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
                        'NAME': '**',
                        'USER': '**',
                        'PASSWORD': '**',
                        'HOST': '**',
                        'PORT': '**'
        }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = "America/New_York"

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ""

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ""

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ""

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = "7@m$nx@q%-$la^fy_(-rhxtvoxk118hrprg=q86f(@k*6^^vf8"


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "conf.urls"

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = "conf.wsgi.application"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates/")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
            "debug": DEBUG,
        },
    }
]

SHARED_APPS = [
    'django_tenants',
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "organizations",
    "accounts",
]


TENANT_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    'vendors',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

# MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',)
# INSTALLED_APPS += ('debug_toolbar',)
INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1",)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {"INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS": False, "TAG": "body"}

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    "debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel",
)


# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {"require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"}},
    "handlers": {
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": True,
        }
    },
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)

TENANT_MODEL = "vendors.Vendor"

TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "vendors.VendorOwner"
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Vendor, VendorUser, VendorOwner


admin.site.register(Vendor)
admin.site.register(VendorUser)
admin.site.register(VendorOwner)
```

When I try to run (after running `./manage.py migrate_schemas --shared`, which works fine) `./manage.py migrate_schemas --tenant`, I get following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "vendors_vendor" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "vendors_vendor"."schema_name" FROM "vendors_vendor" ...
                                                   ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_tenants/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 63, in handle
    executor.run_migrations(tenants=tenants)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/standard.py", line 8, in run_migrations
    tenants = tenants or []
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 184, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1103, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/vineet/projects/env-cosgrid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "vendors_vendor" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "vendors_vendor"."schema_name" FROM "vendors_vendor" ...
```

I searched about it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520466/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-users-user-does-not-exist), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897442/django-1-8-fails-to-django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-auth-user-does)) but they didn't seem to work.

Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I don't know how tenant library works but it is something like your module is not right. Do you have a module named `vendors`? And is the shared `models.py` file in that module?

Comment: yes i have an app named `vendors`

Comment: Do you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Couldn't solve it till now